# Can't get the if statements/while loop to work

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop

Can't get the if statements/while loop to work. If I make raceChosen an int it will never allow me to enter choose another race. When I use a char the if statements don't work. I have absolutely no idea who to fix this. Any assistance that could be provided would be appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct player {   /*a struct to hold the player information.*/
int type[7];
int name[12];
int Smartness[7];
int Strength[7];
int MagicSkills[7];
int Luck[7];
int Dexterity[7];
int lifePoints[3];
}player;



int  main(void)
{
    struct player* ptr;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int numberPlayers,i,j,Smartness,Luck,Strength,Dexterity;
    int MagicSkills,name,slots,x,Hill,City,LevelGround,m,lifePoints;
    lifePoints = 100;
    char raceChosen[1];


    printf("Please enter the number of players you would like");
    scanf("%d",&numberPlayers);  /*take in the number of players*/

    struct player plyr[numberPlayers];
    i = 0;

    while( i<numberPlayers )
    {

    printf("Please enter the race you would like to play as \n"
    "Press elf for Elf \n"
    "Press 1 for Human \n"        /*taking in the race from the user*/
    "Press 2 for Ogre \n"
    "Press 3 for Wizard \n");
    scanf(" %c",&raceChosen);               


    if(raceChosen == "0"){
        printf("Please enter your name \n:");
        scanf("%d", &ptr->name[i]);
        Smartness = rand()%31 + 70;
        printf("%d\n",Smartness);
        scanf("%d", &ptr->Smartness[i]);
        Luck = rand()%41 + 60;
        printf("%d \n",Luck);
        scanf("%d", &ptr->Luck[i]);
        Strength = rand()%50 + 1;
        printf("%d \n",Strength);          /* generating the character */
        scanf("%d", &ptr->Strength[i]);
        Dexterity = rand()%100 + 1;
        printf("%d\n",Dexterity);
        scanf("%d", &ptr->Dexterity[i]);
        MagicSkills = rand()%31 + 50;
        printf("%d \n",MagicSkills);
        scanf("%d", &ptr->MagicSkills[i]);
        printf("\n********\n");

    }


    if(raceChosen == "1"){
        printf("Please enter your name \n:");
        scanf("%d", &ptr->name[i]);
        Smartness = rand()%31 + 70;
        printf("%d\n",Smartness);
        scanf("%d", &ptr->Smartness[i]);
        Luck = rand()%41 + 60;
        printf("%d \n",Luck);
        scanf("%d", &ptr->Luck[i]);
        Strength = rand()%50 + 1;
        printf("%d \n",Strength);
        scanf("%d", &ptr->Strength[i]);
        Dexterity = rand()%100 + 1;
        printf("%d\n",Dexterity);
        scanf("%d", &ptr->Dexterity[i]);
        MagicSkills = rand()%31 + 50;
        printf("%d \n",MagicSkills);
        scanf("%d", &ptr->MagicSkills[i]);
        printf("\n********\n");



    }

    }
    i++;
    }

    }
```

Comment: You must use `strcmp()` to compare strings. Your expressions like `raceChosen == "1"` test a different property and are always false. Also, you posted way too much code.

Comment: `raceChosen == "0"` --> `*raceChosen == '0'`, if `char raceChosen[1];` --> `char raceChosen;`, `raceChosen == "0"` --> `raceChosen == '0'`

Comment: I think you need to describe your problem better. What does `If I use an int` mean? Use an int where?

Comment: if allow type `elf`, `char raceChosen[1];` --> `char raceChosen[4];`, `canf(" %c",&raceChosen);` --> `canf("%3s", raceChosen);`, `raceChosen == "0"` --> `strcmp(raceChosen,  "elf") == 0`, but maybe "Press elf for Elf \n" typo as "Press 0 for Elf \n"

Comment: I have tried using strcmp and it did not work.

Comment: in case of  you use `char raceChosen[1];`, Can't use `strcmp`.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance I have now gotten the if statements working. However when ever I run it it only takes input for every second character. Eg if i run it and choose human it will run through, then go through again and then ask me to choose a race.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would recommend you try to compile your code before asking questions.

Anyways, let's go through your compile errors step by step:

1. Line 43: Passing the wrong variable type to scanf

   You only need one character from standard input, so no need for a string array (char *), just use a character variable (char)

   So `char raceChosen[1]` becomes `char raceChosen`
2. Lines 46 and 69: Comparing two strings with `==` operator

   This is a good reason to start learning the basics of C programming. To compare two strings in C, you use `strcmp(first_string, second_string)`.

   Since raceChosen is not a character array anymore, we don't need strcmp, we can still use `==` but the quotes around 0 and 1 have to be single quotes.

   So your if statements become `if(raceChosen == '0')` and `if(raceChosen == '1')`. This is how you compare two characters.
3. Lines 23, 24 and 32, Lots of unused variables

   I hope you're gonna use those later because this is bad practice.
4. Line 48: Using an uninitialized variable

   Just initialize `ptr` to NULL (`ptr = NULL`) right after you declare it.

   Just a notice tho, you don't need to use a pointer to struct here, unless you were asked to. A simple struct would do the work.
5. Line 98: Extraneous closing brace

   Yup, just as it says, too many closing braces.

Comment: I did compile it and it compiled without any errors. As for the unused variables I only copied the part of the code I had questions on not the full thing. That section just happened to include where I declared the variables that are used later on. The same for the extraneous closing brace I would imagine.

Comment: "So char raceChosen[1] becomes char raceChosen
Lines 46 and 69: Comparing two strings with == operator

This is a good reason to start learning the basics of C programming. To compare two strings in C, you use strcmp(first_string, second_string).

Since raceChosen is not a character array anymore, we don't need strcmp, we can still use == but the quotes around 0 and 1 have to be single quotes.

So your if statements become if(raceChosen == '0') and if(raceChosen == '1'). This is how you compare two characters." Also if I do this the if statements do not work.

Comment: @psudonym55 Are you sure you changed the quotes around 1 and 0? They have to be single quotes. It works fine for me.

Comment: That is working now. Still getting a problem where it will only let me choose a race every second time it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Change like this, i hope it work for you.

```
int  main(void)
{
    struct player* ptr;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i,j,Smartness,Luck,Strength,Dexterity;
    int MagicSkills,name,slots,x,Hill,City,LevelGround,m,lifePoints;
    lifePoints = 100;
    char raceChosen[1];
    static int numberPlayers=0; //Changed

    printf("Please enter the number of players you would like");
    scanf("%d",&numberPlayers);  /*take in the number of players*/

    struct player plyr[numberPlayers];
    i = 0;

    while( i<numberPlayers )
    {

    printf("Please enter the race you would like to play as \n"
    "Press elf for Elf \n"
    "Press 1 for Human \n"        /*taking in the race from the user*/
    "Press 2 for Ogre \n"
    "Press 3 for Wizard \n");
    scanf("%c",&raceChosen);               


    if(*raceChosen == '0'){ //Changed
        printf("Please enter your name \n:");
        scanf("%d", &ptr->name[i]);
        Smartness = rand()%31 + 70;
        printf("%d\n",Smartness);
        scanf("%d", &ptr->Smartness[i]);
        Luck = rand()%41 + 60;
        printf("%d \n",Luck);
        scanf("%d", &ptr->Luck[i]);
        Strength = rand()%50 + 1;
        printf("%d \n",Strength);          /* generating the character */
        scanf("%d", &ptr->Strength[i]);
        Dexterity = rand()%100 + 1;
        printf("%d\n",Dexterity);
        scanf("%d", &ptr->Dexterity[i]);
        MagicSkills = rand()%31 + 50;
        printf("%d \n",MagicSkills);
        scanf("%d", &ptr->MagicSkills[i]);
        printf("\n********\n");

    }


    if(*raceChosen == '1'){ //Changed
        printf("Please enter your name 1\n:");
        scanf("%d", &ptr->name[i]);
        Smartness = rand()%31 + 70;
        printf("%d\n",Smartness);
        scanf("%d", &ptr->Smartness[i]);
        Luck = rand()%41 + 60;
        printf("%d \n",Luck);
        scanf("%d", &ptr->Luck[i]);
        Strength = rand()%50 + 1;
        printf("%d \n",Strength);
        scanf("%d", &ptr->Strength[i]);
        Dexterity = rand()%100 + 1;
        printf("%d\n",Dexterity);
        scanf("%d", &ptr->Dexterity[i]);
        MagicSkills = rand()%31 + 50;
        printf("%d \n",MagicSkills);
        scanf("%d", &ptr->MagicSkills[i]);
        printf("\n********\n");



    }

    }
    i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 major things to be considered within your code, lets correct them one by one:

1. **char raceChosen[1]; <=> Here you have declared a charecter array of size 1**

   Please note : Array is collection of data of same type, so when you want to store at least 2 or more data, you could had used array, but here you are using a single charecter variable so you should avoid using array.

   correct way: char raceChosen;
2. Secondly,

   ```
    scanf(" %c",&raceChosen);
    if (raceChosen == "0")
   ```

Here you are taking input racechosen as a charecter : "%c" is for charecter input, and while comapring you are comapring it with string : " "double quote is for string. ie; You are comapring

```
    if (raceChosen == "0")

       (char)       (string)
```

This condition is not going to be true, hence you are not entering these if blocks.

correct way:

```
   if (raceChosen == '0')

        char         char
```